# Handle multiple options in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

I have this simple bash script

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then du
else
while getopts :d:h:s:r:f:a: option; do
    case $option in
        d) echo 'd';;
        h) echo 'h';;
        s) echo 's';;
        r) echo 'r';;
        f) echo 'f';;
        a) echo 'a';;
        \?) echo 'option invalide,-h pour obtenir I aide' 
    esac
done
fi
```

and when I call it with `./script.sh -d -a` for example I would like to get "d a" returned.

Problem is I only get "d" or "a" if I call it in the other order.

How can I do to have the script doing all present options instructions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `getopt` declared every option to take an argument by following each name with a `:`. As such, `script.sh -d -a` recognizes the `-d` option with argument `-a`, but you ignore the argument. The same holds for `script.sh -a -d`: you recognize `-a` but ignore its `-d` option.

If you omit the `:`s, then the options are simply flags that take no argument, and you'll see each option in turn:

```
while getopts :dhsrfa option; do
```

When you *do* use `:`, the argument provided with the option is available in the `OPTARG` parameter. Try your script with the following:

```
while getopts :d:h:s:r:f:a: option; do
    case $option in
        d) echo "d with $OPTARG";;
        h) echo "h with $OPTARG";;
        s) echo "s with $OPTARG";;
        r) echo "r with $OPTARG";;
        f) echo "f with $OPTARG";;
        a) echo "a with $OPTARG";;
        \?) echo 'option invalide,-h pour obtenir I aide' 
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass more than one argument to your bash script. In general, here is the syntax of passing multiple arguments to any bash script:

script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3  …
The second argument will be referenced by the $2 variable, the third argument is referenced by $3, .. etc.

The $0 variable contains the name of your bash script in case you were wondering!